# SQL Create Table Error

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

I am just beginning to learn SQL and have stumbled at the first hurdle, I am unable to create a table. Below is the code example. The error I am receiving when running the statement, references line 7 stating there is an issue with a 'relational operator'. The purpose of **line 7** is to check that the age of the person is greater than 18.

I am using Oracle (unsure if that will make a difference). I hope someone can point me in the correct direction.

```
1.  CREATE TABLE employee
2.  (
3.  empID         VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL primary key,
4.  surname       VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL CHECK(surname=UPPER(surname)),
5.  deptCode      CHAR(5) NOT NULL CHECK(deptCode=UPPER(deptCode)),
6.  empYear       NUMBER(1,0) NOT NULL CHECK(empYear >= 1 AND empYear <= 4),
7.  birthDate     DATE NOT NULL CHECK((SYSDATE - birthDate) /365 ) >= 18
8.  );
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot define a CHECK constraint that references a function like SYSDATE.

The Oracle documentation has a discussion on the [restrictions on CHECK constraints](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_constraints.htm#sthref684)

Answer (score 1):

Check your parenthesis.

```
DATE NOT NULL CHECK(((SYSDATE - birthDate) /365 ) >= 18)
```

EDIT: As Justin pointed out, you can't use SYSDATE here.